Facing 503 error on PHP files after deleting hidden files from the root folder
I am in the process of transferring my Wordpress website to Zume hosting. The website was working fine on my previous hosting provider. After uploading the files and database to Zume (using file manager), and making sure that wp_config.php and the database configuration is correct, I initially faced an error Error establishing a database connection, even though a test PHP scripts successfully connected with the database. While attempting to fix the database issue, I accidentally deleted hidden files in the root directory of my site (outside the public_html folder), while making a backup.
After restoring these files, I am now experiencing a new problem: PHP files return a 503 Service Unavailable error, while HTML files work normally. I've attempted various troubleshooting steps, such as:

Checking file permissions and ownership.
Confirming PHP versions and
configurations.
Adjusting the .htaccess file.
Testing with simple PHP
scripts.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists.
I can delete the whole website and start again, but I would prefer to try debug this first. Any tips?

This sounds like a question for the hosting company.  Can you fire up a new instance on the host and re-migrate?
